# How to run a program automatically in Ubuntu?

Tags: scripts, executable

How can I run a program in the Terminal automatically in Ubuntu?

[image]

How to make a shell script to print the output into a text file?

Comment: Are you aware that you're trying to use a Windows program with Ubuntu? Or do you use Wine?

Comment: What do you mean "automatically"? What is this program? How does it take input?

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean, I want to run a program (print_tokens.c) use a parameter taken from the other folder(for example: bug6.123.10). both of them are in the different folder. the tree is like picture above. so the pattern should be like this :(gcc print_tokens.c bug6.123.10.)

Answer (score 0):

Install `Wine` by

> sudo apt-get install wine

Then follow these steps,

[image]

[image]

Save Your file with `.sh` extension & then run from terminal like this

> sh filename.sh

Comment: or else just replace replace just sdXx with `sda1` or `sda2` to your hdd keep `/media`

Comment: Why do you assume that the script can take a file as input or that that file is expected to be passed as an argument? If this is a classic windows GUI program it almost certainly can't. There is no need for the `sh` extension and it doesn't apply here anyway since you're not making an executable script with a shebang line.

Comment: I'm sorry, because I'm newby here.

this is the tree of my folder. I have an SIEMENS program for software testing, and I try to run  the program in Ubuntu 12.04. but I don't know how to run it, because the program and the input file 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2a6vockv8qqmp6d/tree.JPG

I want to run print_tokens.c in terminal. The program use a parameter taken from inputs folder (for example : gcc print_tokens.c bug6.123.10 ).

there are more than 4000 files input. I want to run program print_tokens.c with all the input files automatically, because to many files to run it manually.

thank you

Comment: you should have mention that in question. That means you have to run your SIEMENS program, for doing that type this in terminal `wine SIEMENS_PROGRAM`. but first install wine using my answer!